# How to import data from one excel file to another by user?

Tags: excel, vba, database, import, connector

All I need to do is import data from one excel to another by microsoft user. Please let me explain my business model and look at the example below.

My business model works like this:

Every salesman is responsible for his own country... Legally he can see only his country's data. So I want to create file on salesmen's desktops which can import their personalized data from the database in excel.

Database:

[image]

For example - Salesman 1 would see only this:

[image]

Can I do it in a safe way? I was considering macros, but I think that this solution is too fragile and it might be too easy to break the passwords. Please advice..

Comment: The only thing that I can think of : each time the database is changed/updated, create a separate xlsx file based on each country (using macro) then share/give the file to the intended sales.

Comment: create a column for the salesman name same row as the country then it is easy to copy and salesman, country and sales into a new workbook